# How to retrieve onSaveInstanceState() bundle in onResume()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am having a problem related to saving my Activity state. I searched and read about lots of questions here in SO but I couldn't get an answer for my question.

I have an `Activity` A with 2 `Fragments`. The `Activity` A holds the data which is showed by the `Fragments`. When I launch a new `Intent` for my settings `Activity` the `Activity` A is paused (not destroyed), `onPause()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` methods are called, so I save all my data in `onSaveInstaceState()`.

When I return from my settings using back button `Activity` A is displayed again but `onCreate()` method is not being called because the `Activity` was not destroyed, instead `onResume()` method is called but I lost the state of my variables in `Activity` A and I can't access the `Bundle` I saved in `onSaveInstanceState()` because `onCreate()` is not called.

So `onSaveInstanceState()` is only useful when you rotate the screen? How can I access all the data I saved in `onSaveInstanceState()`? Or I should save them to a file or `SharedPrefs` to access them in `onResume()` later?

Comment: It isn't making much sense... you've lost the data of your instance variables declared on Acitivy A? They went null?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Can this help?
1. Use `getIntent().putExtras()` in `onStop()` to save your data into Activity's bundle.
2. Then `getIntent().getExtras()` in `onResume()` to retrieve it.

And you should do a null check before access the bundle :)

Comment: Worked great! To save the data I used `getIntent().putExtras()` because `getIntent().getExtras()` is null at that time where you didn't save anything yet.

Comment: Can you share an example? I'm trying to implement this in onStop/onResume, but not having much luck.

Comment: It's incredible how Android Developers recommend us to use `onSaveInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onCreate` but it is very unstable. Thanks for sharing this, it solved my problem

Comment: Just get null when call `getIntent().getExtras()` in `onResume()`.  More detail, please?

Comment: What happens if the user goes through multiple other activities and eventually comes back to the original activity? intents when they come back might be overridden.

Comment: wouldn't onPause() be better paired with onResume(), or onStop() + onStart()?

Answer (score -3):

You can save all the stuff from SavedInstance in the bundle or variable.

And set the data on onActivityCreated method like  :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Do your stuff here

}
```

Comment: Sometimes onActivityCreated not called.